# Problem getting the correct value when using xml.etree

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to export all the movie titles from an xml file but I can't seem to get the titles. The xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<videodb>
    <version>1</version>
    <movie>
        <title>2 Guns</title>
        <originaltitle>2 Guns</originaltitle>
        <ratings>
            <rating name="themoviedb" max="10" default="true">
                <value>6.500000</value>
                <votes>1776</votes>
            </rating>
        </ratings>
```

I've seen lots of examples for values where xml has `value="title"` but can't find a guiding example that works when there is no `value="title"`

My code so far:

```
#Import required library
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('D:\\temp\\videodb.xml').getroot()

for type_text in root.findall('movie/title'):
    value = type_text.get ('text')
    print(value)
```

Comment: Try `value = type_text.text`

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the closing tags for the example XML? Ideally the example will [minimal but complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think all it needs is `</movie>` and `</videodb>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<videodb>
    <version>1</version>
    <movie>
        <title>2 Guns</title>
        <originaltitle>2 Guns</originaltitle>
        <ratings>
            <rating name="themoviedb" max="10" default="true">
                <value>6.500000</value>
                <votes>1776</votes>
            </rating>
        </ratings>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Top Gun</title>
        <originaltitle>Top Gun</originaltitle>
        <ratings>
            <rating name="themoviedb" max="10" default="true">
                <value>7.500000</value>
                <votes>1566</votes>
            </rating>
        </ratings>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Inception</title>
        <originaltitle>Inceptions</originaltitle>
        <ratings>
            <rating name="themoviedb" max="10" default="true">
                <value>9.500000</value>
                <votes>177346</votes>
            </rating>
        </ratings>
    </movie>
</videodb>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('E:\Python\DataFiles\movies.xml') # replace with your path
root = tree.getroot()
for aMovie in root.iter('movie'):
    print(aMovie.find('title').text)
```

Output:

```
2 Guns
Top Gun
Inception
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```py
value = type_text.get ('text')
```

with

```py
value = type_text.text
```

`xml.etree` uses [`Element.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get) to retrieve the content element *attributes*.

You're after the element *text*; see [Element.text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text).

For example, given this contrived XML:

```xml
<element some_attribute="Some Attribute">Some Text</element>
```

`.get('some_attribute')` would return `Some Attribute` while `.text` would return `Some Text`.